# set padding to all textview at a time programmatically android

Tags: android, textview

on view lots of Text view are present, for all Text view can i set padding at a time like

```
 TextView ccc_about_us_heading=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ccc_about_us_heading);
 TextView ccc_about_us_description=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.ccc_about_us_description);

 ccc_about_us_heading,ccc_about_us_description.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
```

Comment: create `LayoutParam` and setPadding and then add param to all textview.

Comment: how exactly ? im really new to android

Comment: Add all the text view inside an linear or relative layout and then you should set padding for layout it will apply for all text views

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. Just like...

```
ccc_about_us_heading.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
ccc_about_us_description.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
```

And you can't create a list of textView's and set padding in loop, like this...

```
myTextViewArray=Arrays.asList(ccc_about_us_description,ccc_about_us_heading)
        for(TextView textView: myTextViewArray){
          textView.setPadding(5,5,5,5);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
List<View> tvList = new ArrayList<>();

tvList.add(ccc_about_us_heading);
tvList.add(ccc_about_us_description);
// add all your views

for(View v:tvList)
{
    v.setPadding(left, top, right, bottom);
}
```